# Why can't I get scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I am trying to make an element appear after a certain scrolling has occurred to do this I'm using scrollTop() but I always get 0.

```
$(document).on("mousewheel", function(){
                   console.log($(window).scrollTop());
               });
```

instead of `window` I've tried `body`, `#wrapper` and `document` but with all of those I get a constant 0. What am I missing to get a proper read? (`#wrapper` has no set height just a width.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your code under $(document).ready(), in other words, 
Has the [DomContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_%28event%29) event triggered before your code execute?

.scrollTop() will give correct result only when document has been loaded completely.

can you give a detailed example?

Sidenote: $(document).on('event', callback) works irrespective on whether document is fully loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Question  - does it have to be "mousewheel"? I do not believe there is a mousewheel handler unless you use a jquery plugin.

do this and it works for me:

```
           $(document).on("scroll", function(){
               console.log($(window).scrollTop());
           });
```